# Show modal dialog box when cell1 value is greater than cell2 value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where in "Sheet1", cell C13 is not supposed to have a numerical value greater than in cell F19. Is there a way that the user could be shown a dialog box in case the above event happens?
Thank you very much

Comment: In your situation, how are the cells "C13" or "C19" edited? I thought that the approach to achieving your goal depends on the method for editing the cells. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: They are both calculated by the formula =SUM() of a range of cells

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `They are both calculated by the formula =SUM() of a range of cells`, in this case, unfortunately, when "C13" or "C19" is edited, the OnEdit trigger cannot be used. So, it is required to think of another approach. So, from your reply, I would like to ask one more question to correctly understand your actual situation. In your situation, what cell is manually edited, and the values of the formulas of `=SUM()` in "C13" and "C19" are changed? In this case, I thought that the original cell might be able to be used as the target cell for the OnEdit trigger.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so clearly. “C13” is the sum of cells is =SUM(C6:C12) and cell “F19” is =SUM(C19:D19)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I cannot still know the method for changing the cells "C6:C12" and "C19:D19" in your situation. But, by guessing that those cells are manually edited, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `They are both calculated by the formula =SUM() of a range of cells` and `“C13” is the sum of cells is =SUM(C6:C12) and cell “F19” is =SUM(C19:D19)` in your reply, if in your situation, the cells "C6:C12" and "C19:D19" are manually edited and you want to check the values of "C13" and "C19", in your situation, how about checking the cells "C6:C12" and "C19:D19"? When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name, and save the script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const check1 = range.rowStart >= 6 && range.rowStart <= 12 && range.columnStart == 3;
  const check2 = range.rowStart == 19 && range.columnStart >= 3 && range.columnStart <= 4;
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && (check1 || check2)) {
    const [c13, f19] = ["C13", "F19"].map(r => sheet.getRange(r).getValue());
    if (c13 > f19) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("'C13 > F19' is true.");
    }
  }
}
```

- In this script, when you manually edited one of the cells "C6:C12" and "C19:D19", the script is run. The script checks the edited range and checks the values of cells "C13" and "F19". When the value of "C13" is larger than that of "F19", a dialog is opened.

#### Note:

- From your reply, I proposed a sample script. But, I cannot still know the method for changing the cells "C6:C12" and "C19:D19" in your situation. So, when these cells are manually edited, the above script can be used. But, if these cells are not manually edited, it is required to know the origin for editing the cells. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I am sorry for forgetting to mention how they are edited. Cells C6:C12 & C19:D19 are all entered manually by the user. I will try out your script asap!

Comment: @Anushka Thank you for replying. From `Cells C6:C12 & C19:D19 are all entered manually by the user.` in your reply, I think that my proposed script can be used. Please test it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `onEdit(e)` trigger.  When the user enters a value in Sheet1!C13 the function uses the event object `e`, compares with the value in Shee1!F19 and displays an alert.

I always enclose my code in a try{} catch(){} block as a matter of habit.  To control where the error message goes.

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if( sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      if( e.range.getA1Notation() === "C13" ) {
        if( e.value > sheet.getRange("F19").getValue() ) {
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("C13 value is greater than F19");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Error in onEdit: "+err);
  }
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#alert(String))
- [Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String))